# Saving Multiline Strings to a JSON file from a Textfield

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have an app that gives the user the ability to type and save text in a `TextField`. It works just fine if the text entered into the `TextField` is one continues line. If the user presses the return/enter key to create a new line in the `TextField` it does not save to the JSON file properly. Is there a way to save multiline text from a `TextField` to a JSON file?

```
        Flexible(
            child: TextField(
            controller: _notesController,
            obscureText: false,
            maxLines: null,
            onChanged: (value) {
                // updates playterNotes to the text inputed
                playerList.players[index].playerNotes = value;
                
                // updates JSON file
                writePlayerData(playerList);
            },
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 174, 3, 1.0),
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
                fontSize: 14.0,
                fontFamily: 'Smash'
            ),
            ),
        )
```

Edit:
If the JSON file doesn't save correctly, I load a placeholder JSON.

This is the JSON printed out after the initial 'single line'

```
I/flutter ( 4058): {"players":[{"id": "GitHub Test","setCount": "0 - 0","characters": {"char1": "cloud","char2": ""},"notes": "single line"}]}
```

This is the JSON printed out after 'multi line'

```
I/flutter ( 4058): {"players":[{"id": "GitHub Test","setCount": "0 - 0","characters": {"char1": "cloud","char2": ""},"notes": "single line
I/flutter ( 4058): multi line"}]}
```

[image: Test]

WritePlayerData:

```
Future<File> writePlayerData(PlayerList playerList) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  return file.writeAsString(PlayerListtoJson(playerList));
}
```

Which calls:

```
String PlayerListtoJson(PlayerList playerList) {
  String playerJson = "";

  if (playerList.players.length  > 0 ) {
    playerJson = '{"players":[${playerToJson(playerList.players)}]}';
  }
  return playerJson;
}

String playerToJson(List<Player> players) {
  String playerString = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    playerString += '{"id": "${players[i].playerId}",'
        '"setCount": "${players[i].playerSetCount}",'
        '"characters": ${characterToJson(players[i].playerChars)}'
        '"notes": "${players[i].playerNotes}"}';

    if (!(i == players.length - 1)) {
      playerString += ',';
    }
  }
  return playerString;
}

String characterToJson (Characters characters) {
  String playerCharacters = '{"char1": "${characters.char1}",'
      '"char2": "${characters.char2}"},';

  return playerCharacters;
}
```

Reference JSON:

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "id": "Filler Character",
      "setCount": "0 - 0",
      "characters": {
        "char1": "",
        "char2": ""
      },
      "notes": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If writing the JSON file does not work the way you want... you need to show us the "writing to the JSON file" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the new line with a `\` so the encoder doesn't insert a new line in the JSON produced

```
String s = 'A\nB\nC';
print('$s');
//A
//B
//C
//escaping the new line with a additional "\"
s = s.split('\n').join('\\n');
//or
//s.replaceAll('\n', '\\n');
print('$s');
//A\nB\nC
```